# Why does IE make password boxes smaller than text boxes?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, rendering

See the simple form below. It's just a text box on top of a password box. If you look at it in Internet Explorer 7 (and 8, and probably others) the text box is 10 pixels wider than the password box.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>IE Text vs. Password test</title>
</head>
<body>                 

<form action="test"> 
  <p>
    <input type="text"><br>  
    <input type="password">      
  </p>
</form>          

</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to "fix" that globally, either through CSS or by adding something to the HTML?

Comment: As for the why, I'd guess it has something to do with "guessing" how many characters might fit into the box (the size attribute also tells, how many characters should fit). And as an asterisk or bullet is smaller than a lower-case m, for example ... you get differing widths.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Because different font is used in those types of fields.

The fix is simply to specify that all inputs use the same font.

```
<style type="text/css">
  input {
      font-family: sans-serif;                
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could append a fixed width for all inputs on the current page:

```
<style type="text/css">
input {
    width: 10em;    
}
</style>
```

Comment: Note that this will set the width for all of your input elements, not just textboxes. Recommend setting a class of "textbox" on your textboxes, and then having a CSS style for input.textbox

Comment: @Richard E. Why set a class? input[type="text"],input[type="password"]

Answer (score 3):

The problem is Internet Explorer's default encoding. Internet Explorer has an issue displaying the field lengths the same when using UTF-8 encoding. In IE, try changing the encoding to "Windows" (Page->Encoding in IE 8) while viewing a problem page and you'll see exactly what I mean.

Comment: Can't upvote this answer enough!  Never would have guessed that the encoding would be the cause, but this solved my problem _perfectly_!

Answer (score 1):

If you include the jQuery library in your page(s), you can use the following code to:

"When the document is fully loaded, take the first input element with type='text', and apply it's height and width to all input elements with type='password'".

I tested this on IE7 only, and it worked like a charm.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("input[type='password']").height($("input[type='text']").height());
$("input[type='password']").width($("input[type='text']").width());

});
</script>
```

This is a generalized answer (taking the first element that matches input[type='text']).  You can get a reference to a particular element that you want to match, and then get a reference to one or more password boxes with some other jQuery selector.  Have a look at the documentation for getting elements by id or a group of elements by a common css class or xpath-type expression:

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

Answer (score 0):

Setting the width on textboxes will solve but I assume that's not what you want.

Try setting the min-width on input[type=text], input[type=password] to something greater than the default for textboxes. You'll probably need http://deanedwards.me.uk 's IE8 script to make those selectors work.

Answer (score 0):

The font size is irrelevant.  as seen in this test here:
http://build.jhousemedia.com/ie_test.php

I wish I could give you a solid answer as to why but the work around is to apply a fixed width to it.

Comment: Your test shows that the font size is most relevant. Don't you see that there is a diffence in size between the first two fields and the next two fields that has a different font size?