# IE 10 Automatically decrease my password length in php form submission

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can anyone help me out from this issue ?

When i try to submit form in codeigniter in **IE10** Browser my password field length is decrease but still i can login into this.

Is there any way to **stop decreasing my password length** beacuse all other browser works fine.

Thank You.

Comment: I don't think your password length is cut, when you can still log in. Isn't it only html form field size issue?

Comment: no i don't think so because other browsers works fine

Comment: Check this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/690147/why-does-ie-make-password-boxes-smaller-than-text-boxes

Answer (score 0):

Just an appearance method so no one knows the actual length of your password. If a hacker see's and knows he is only looking for 8 characters, it may make his job easier. I always use 25 characters and some sites make it look like 10 characters. Its no problem